# iPhone Addressbook and contact id? does it ever change?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

Each contact in the address book, has a unique Id,

1) will this Id ever change? if so when does it change? ie a user deletes a contact, will the other contact id change?  how do we make sure of this? will not change now or in the future.

EDIT: would like to uniquely identify a contact, which id should I use as a reference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/DirectInteraction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH6-SW2) says:

> The recommended way to keep a
>   long-term reference to a particular
>   record is to store the first and last
>   name, or a hash of the first and last
>   name, in addition to the identifier.
>   When you look up a record by ID,
>   compare the record’s name to your
>   stored name. If they don’t match, use
>   the stored name to find the record,
>   and store the new ID for the record.

Answer (score 1):

Have one unique field like contact or address and compare the record's name with that field as well as id.